# Can we await in a queue-triggered function that start an orchestration?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

As the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2C2x-durable-functions&pivots=programming-language-csharp#client-usage), I have a queue-triggered function that starts the orchestration. I know in Durable Functions, we cannot await in orchestration code. We can await in the Activity function. But is the code below an "orchestration" code? Or is it just a normal queue-triggered function?

I want to call and await some async methods before starting the actual orchestrator. So far, no issue, but I just want to double-check because the doc is a bit unclear to me.

```cs
[FunctionName("QueueStart")]
public static Task Run(
    [QueueTrigger("durable-function-trigger")] string input,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
{
    await MyAsyncTask(); // Can we await here?
    return starter.StartNewAsync<string>("HelloWorld", input);
}
```

Can we await in the func above? Does the async-await limitation apply here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is the code below an "orchestration" code? Or is it just a normal queue-triggered function?

AFAIK, It is just a normal trigger function which is calling the `DurableOrchestrationClient`,which is just to start a new Orchestration. The Orchestration function is defined separately.

You can use `await` in the Trigger function.

For reference check this Documents.

- [Durable Orchestrations - Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations?tabs=csharp-inproc)
- [Durable orchestrator code constraints - Azure Functions | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-code-constraints?tabs=csharp)

**#My code:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp6
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            var outputs = new List<string>();

            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));

            return outputs;
        }

        [FunctionName(nameof(SayHello))]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [FunctionName("Function1_QueueTrigger")]
        public static async Task Run(
            [QueueTrigger("testqueue", Connection ="QueueConnnectionstring")] string message,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
            // Function input comes from the request content.
            await MyAsyncTask();
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

            log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

        }

        private static async Task MyAsyncTask()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from MyAsyncTask");
        }
    }
}
```

**#`OUTPUT`:**
[image]